# Trajectory of light ray in constant gravitational field

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, geodesics

A light ray is shot from a laser at angle $\theta$ from the ground (upwards). Assuming a constant gravitational field, what shape is the trajectory?

Looking at [Wikipedia-Rindler Coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates), I find an expression for null-geodesics in Rindler spacetime. Taking the plane of motion to be $y=0$, the trajectory $x(z)$ is an ellipse with $\frac{dx}{dz}|_{z=0}=\infty$. It seems like no choice of parameters gives an angle different from $\pi/2$ at $z=0$.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything. That is correct. Recall that the $ z=0 $ surface is the Rindler horizon, which is itself a null surface. It is therefore not surprising that light rays always intersect it perpendicularly.

The ground is at some $z > 0$ which is determined by the local acceleration of gravity $g$. The lower $g$ is at ground level the larger $z$ is at ground level.

Comment: Thanks!
1.Could you please give the connection between $z_0$ and $g$?
2. Does that mean that the solution to the original Earth problem is that the trajectory is an ellipse?

Comment: If everything is in natural units then $g=1/z$ for a stationary observer at $z$. I would not describe the Rindler solution as a good solution for Earth except over very small distances. It is for a hypothetical uniform gravitational field. In natural units the solutions are semicircles that are orthogonal to the Rindler horizon at $z=0$